# kernel-update for new hardware?

Tags: kernel

will there be an update to kernel 4.19 LTS or higher soon? i have brand new laptop/hardware that would benefit from it.

ukuu oddly enough doesn't display 4.19 LTS. how can i switch to 4.19 LTS (complete newbie) without ukuu?

i already had experience with this kernel with another linux - os (but switched to you) - lower cpu- temperature on my system was a significant advantage.

otherwise: best distro of all. thx.

Answer (score 1):

you could try the HWE kernel: [RollingLTSEnablementStack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/RollingLTSEnablementStack)

You can install the HWE Kernel in the terminal:

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-18.04
```

This installs currently the 4.18 kernel.

Comment: thx, but unfortunately the console gives me the answer: e: using the regular expression "linux-generic-hwe-18.04" no package could be found.

Comment: done. but by ukuu. i first updated to 4.19.4. a stable kernel: https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.19.4/

Comment: done. but by ukuu. i updated to: 4.19.14. the system works smooth (+ **extremely** lower cpu-temperature (pursuant to "sensors" & psensor)). now i wait until ukuu displays 4.20.4 . also stable and apparently ubuntu - LTS: https://www.ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle thx anyway tux! ps: suggestion @elementary: a kernel updater, integrated in the OS, would be very important (imho). exactly for the reason, which is summarized here in the first contribution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/248914/what-is-hardware-enablement-hwe

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15437)

Comment: i gave _myself a complete answer_. not "additional information". and why are some parts of my post deleted?

Comment: Welcome to eOS. Your participation is much appreciated. I assume, this answer you posted here is a comment on tuxaino answer.

Comment: sry, at the beginning, this forum is a little disheveling. i'm getting used to it. all ok.